# How to add extension to img src directory when uploaded file's name changed?

Tags: php, html, file, file-upload

I have a php script for this form which uploads user file (takes the file to a directory and changes it's name with the id of that image from the database table while keeping extension) and a while loop which shows results from 2 different tables. in this while loop tried to show the image as a link.

I've written code below temporarily for adding ".jpg" extension to the image source directory. bcs ".$row['ID']" only returns the ID number and not the extension.

what's a good method to add the extension of the file to the source directory and how to do it?

keep in mind that I'm somewhat beginner at php and I'd like to learn with the explanation of the code. like which string is for what, which method is for what..

thank you very much for your time.

```
<a href="#"><img src= "./images/<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>.jpg" alt="no image"/></a>
```

Comment: It seems to be OK. What you are getting in the browser's source ?

Comment: no the code is working but It only works for ".jpg" but I actually want this code to find out the extension of the current file.

should I add another column to the table to register it's new name and use $row to show that column instead? is this an effective way to do this?

Comment: So are you wanting it to check if the image is something other than a .jpg like a .png for example? Not really understanding what your goal is.

Comment: let's say it's name was "momo_3124134.png" when user uploads this file; I register this name to a table in the database and I give the auto increment colum's value to the uploaded file as a name. let's say it was 444th file on the table so it's new name in it's directory is like this "/images/444.png"

now when I use while loop to show results I use the code in the question and it only gets ID number and no extension. so if I don't add ".jpg" string myself file doesn't show up. and I want it to get the extension automatically.

Comment: You can update the of name of the image before using _move_uploaded_file()_ feature into the database and then try to fetch that from the database.

Comment: I actually put uploaded file into directory first, then register to the table to get the ID number then rename it. I als would like to keep track of the original name too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is somewhat your table looks like

```
id       filename
---      --------
444      momo_3124134.png
```

In this case, you can access the columns `id` and 'filename` in the while loop. Use the following code to get the file extension and display the file accordingly.

```
<?php
  $filename = 'momo_3124134.png';
  $id = 444;
  $path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
  $filename_to_display = $id.'.'.$path_parts['extension'];
  echo $filename_to_display;
?>
```

Comment: yes this is working great and exactly what I was looking for. thank you very much as soon as I get 15 reputation I'll up vote your answer too.